# How to get MySQL Workbench generating SQL without defining DELIMITERs?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench, code-generation, delimiter

In my model I defined some procedures. When I use the "Forward Engineering", in the generated every procedure gets a `DELIMITER` definition:

```
-- schema
CREATE DATABASE ...
CREATE TABLE foo ...
-- procedures
DELIMITER $$
...
  BEGIN
    ...
  END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I need the SQL as input for the [`PDO#exec(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) and notice now, that the execution stops on the line of the first `DELIMITER` definition. But without defining delimiters it works.

**How to use MySQL Workbench to generate SQL code with procedures without `DELIMITER` statements?**

Comment: The delimiter statements are important. You can either edit them out or use multi query to execute them

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get MySQL Workbench to output a CREATE PROCEDURE statement without delimiters. But I haven't investigated that fully. Without the DELIMITER statements, a semicolon that appears in the procedure definition will be interpreted as the end of the CREATE PROCEDURE statement (a semicolon is the default delimiter.) It's important to override that, to change the statement delimiter to something other than a semicolon, if the procedure includes a semicolon.  The mysqldump utility does the same thing (adds DELIMITER statements around MySQL stored programs).

Comment: @spencer7593 Thank you for detailed explanation!